# apache tomcat IE caching problem

Tags: internet-explorer, cache, ubuntu, apache-2.2, tomcat6

I'm running apche2 and tomcat6 both on port 80 with mod_jk setup on ubuntu servers(8.10,9.10). Tomcat is being used for serving jsp pages. I've a small problem with the IE browser which doesn't cache but just reload all the images(jpg|png|css) when refreshed the page which is not happing with the other browsers. I also tried appending the following in the apache config file but no change.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
 </IfModule>
```

---

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf file:

```
Alias / /var/www/
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
JkMount / myworker
JkMount /* myworker
JkMount /*.jsp myworker
JkUnMount /*.html myworker


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName station1.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapps1
        JkMount /* myworker
        JkUnMount /*.html myworker
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName station2.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapps2
        JkMount /* myworker
    JkMount /*.html myworker
</VirtualHost>
```

Anybody has any trick to make IE cache and not to reload all the images everytime?

Answer (score 0):

We didn't have much luck getting IE to cache until adding something like this to the apache configuration for files matching images and stylesheet extensions:

`Header add Cache-Control "max-age=28800, public"`